StreamingHttpResponse redirect it Django
I am facing problem in showing the status in the scanned
this basically scans the QR of a Coupon and tells that weather the coupon is valid or not
i have stored the status of each coupon in the database along with coupon id
i have figured out the comparison part and to update the database
But
I'm not able to display the status of the i.e weather the coupon is valid or not
the below is the camera.html code
{% include 'header.html' %}
    
        <div  class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:60px;">
            
            <div>
                <img src="/cameraOn/">
                {{print}}
                kjhjvh
            </div>
        </div>

{% include 'footer.html' %}

The below is the views.py code
def scan_qr(request):        
    return render(request, 'camera.html')



@gzip.gzip_page   
def cameraView(request):    
    stat = False
    cam = qr_scanner.VideoCamera()
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(cam, stat), content_type = "multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")



def gen(camera, stat):
    
    while not stat:
        frame, stat = camera.get_frame()
        if stat:
            yield b'--text \r\n' + b'Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n' + b'Hello\r\n\r\n'
        yield (b'--frame \r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

The below is my qr_scanner.py
import cv2
import threading
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode 
from services.models import Service


class VideoCamera(object):

    thread_flag = True
    scanned_otp = 'no_data'
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        _, self.frame = self.video.read()
        self.qr_scanned = False
        threading.Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()

    def release_camera(self):
        self.video.release()
        self.thread_flag = False

    def get_frame(self):
        
        img = self.frame
        _, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', img)


        # Qr Scanning Start

        self.qr_data = ''

        for i in decode(img):
            self.qr_data = i.data.decode('utf-8')
            self.qr_scanned = True

            cv2.waitKey(3)                     

        # Qr Scanning ends

        self.data_list = self.qr_data.split(',')
        if self.qr_scanned and len(self.data_list) == 3:
            self.scanned_otp = self.data_list[2]
            self.check_qr(self.scanned_otp)
            self.release_camera()
            


        return jpeg.tobytes(), self.qr_scanned


    def check_qr(self,otp):
        service_db = Service.objects.filter(coupon_id = otp)
        if service_db.exists() and service_db.first().status == False:
            Service.objects.filter(coupon_id = otp).update(status = True)
            print('Exists')
        else:
            print("not")
        
    
    def update(self):
        try:
            while self.thread_flag:
                _, self.frame = self.video.read()
        except:
            pass
             


This is my 1st time handling a project
And im very new to the coding world
and also to say that i started to learn django via this project
So any help will be very helpful

I tried sending metadata and tried to display it But I wasn't able to update the metadata each time
I tried to redirect the file but it didn't work
I even tried to use a database but the bug is that if multiple users use the app simultaneously then there will be a great inconsistency. The reason this matters i that i need to use this project to our college technical event to manage the coupon thus its very important.

